# I can not go to "EventHandler" with double click

Tags: c#, winforms, button, double-click

When `btnAsset` is double-clicked, it should go to `allButton_Click`.
But it only goes in one click. how can I do that?

```
public void Add(MainForm frm)
{
    this.form1 = frm;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            btnAsset[i] = new Button();
            btnAsset[i].Tag = i;
            btnAsset[i].Name = "Asset-" + i.ToString();
            btnAsset[i].Width = 150;
            btnAsset[i].Height = 120;
            btnAsset[i].Visible = true;
            btnAsset[i].BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

            form1.flowLayoutVideo.Controls.Add(btnAsset[i]);

           btnAsset[i].DoubleClick += new EventHandler(allButton_Click);
        }
  }
```

should go here when double clicked

```
void allButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button p = sender as Button;
    if (p != null)
    {
        int i = (int)p.Tag;
        MessageBox.Show((i + 1).ToString() + ". seçildi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand your questions with some details? Is it WinForms or WPF? Can you show the exact definition of that view (button array)?

Comment: I am using WinForms

Comment: Let me understand. You go to _allButton_Click_ with one click at runtime or when you are designing your form in the forms designer?

Comment: I want to go to the "allButton_Click" method when I double click on the "btnAsset [i]" button.

Comment: my goal is to go to a metod when double clicking on one of the buttons. and to learn the value of "i"

Comment: A button control only ever raises its Click event.  Double-clicking a button is too obscure, no user will ever think that it might do something useful.  They assume a single click is enough.  Make it so.

Answer (score 1):

Look what the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.doubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) says about it:

> By default, the `ControlStyles.StandardClick` and `ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick` style bits are set to false for the Button control, and the DoubleClick event is not raised.

You can change this behaviour by creating your own button class deriving from `Button` and change the style bits.